# How to download OpenGL?

Tags: windows-10, opengl

I can't run a game because it needs OpenGL.

[image: OpenGL error]

I'm not sure what site of what file I'm going to download: http://glew.sourceforge.net/

My system is Windows 10, 64 bit.

Comment: Download OpenGL? You can't just "download" and install it. OpenGL is an API that is part of your video drivers, what GPU and driver do you have? Also, might want to do some research, I don't think Warcraft 3 I'd compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: @acejavelin I had a Windows 10 laptop before... just got broke, there I was ABLE to play Warcraft 3 without any problem.

Comment: Regardless, OpenGL can't just be installed, it is an API that is part of your graphics card drivers. Try running in Windows XP compatibility mode, run as administrator, check the start shortcut and see if it includes `-opengl` parameter and remove it. Just some ideas, the webz is full of potential fixes for Warcraft 3 on Win10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually @acejavelin is right. It is only included in your graphics card's drivers.

There are many games which settings or preferences are written into a single file under its directory. You may alter the preferences to that file to have the game run on DirectX (if it supports DirectX). Not only DirectX settings but all other configurations. Since you didn't provide the game you're playing this is so far the answer I can give you.

In the case of Frozen Throne, I found this on [TomsHardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/122380-13-warcraft-launch-windows), there are users who tried to put "-opengl" in the target of the shortcut file of the game. See following...

> SuniusSep 27, 2012, 3:58 PM
> at the end. Make it like this:
>
> "E:\Warcraft 3\Warcraft III\Warcraft III.exe" -opengl

this is just one of the users who's situation is different from yours.

If that's the case then try the opposite

> "E:\Warcraft 3\Warcraft III\Warcraft III.exe" -directx

Either way works for me but, it's worth giving a try if it works.

---

Another fix is that even though it works with just using a basic display adapter, you must install your on-board's or extended graphics card's drivers.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warcraft_III:_The_Frozen_Throne) is the game.

Comment: Check my edit. Also come back to me when it works. Give it a try

Comment: Hey, did it work?

Comment: Thanks, but both don't work (-opengl , -directx). Just few days ago this trick: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Warcraft III\Frozen Throne.exe" -opengl` still works. Then just now It suddenly not.

Comment: did you install your system's graphics card driver?

Comment: Thank you. After updating my Driver it works! For now it's working fine.... I don't know in the long run. :)

Comment: It will work fine fore long, just dont mess up with your drivers' files